# Spring 5.3.9 - Bean with constructor getting dependency error

Tags: spring-mvc

Using Spring 5.3.9. I have a been with constructor as below .

```
@Component
public class PersonCertificateResults {

    private String certificateId;
    private String discipline;
    private String status;  
        
        
    public PersonCertificateResults(String certificateId, String discipline, String status) {
        super();
        this.certificateId = certificateId;
        this.discipline = discipline;
        this.status = status;   
        
    }
```

DOAImpl - method.

```
@Override
    public List<PersonCertificateResults> getPersonCertificateResults(String personID) throws Exception {

        String searchQuery = "select * from Person where person_id_ignore ='"+ personID + "' ;
        
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                searchQuery,
                (rs, rowNum) ->                        
                new PersonCertificateResults(
                                Integer.toString(rs.getInt("KEY")),
                                rs.getString("DISCIPLINE"),
                                rs.getString("STATUS")                                
                                
                        )
        );
        
        
    }
```

Getting error when restarting the app as "No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}"

Comment: Any help please?